# Embedding a google map into a java JFrame

Tags: java, google-maps, jframe

hey guys i'm trying to embed a dynamic Google map into a JFrame (just a JFrame), is this possible or am I barking up the wrong tree

Answer (score 0):

Youll need to add a Swing component that can render everything that Google maps uses. I think that may be difficult, but im sure one probably exists.

This may be useful: [link](http://djproject.sourceforge.net/ns/index.html)

UPDATE:

I just tried Google maps with this component in a JFrame. Worked beautifully :)

Answer (score 0):

You can add a browser view in JFrame and load google map in that browser.

```
    Browser browser = BrowserFactory.create();
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Google Map");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.add(browser.getView().getComponent(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.setSize(600, 400);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    browser.loadURL("http://maps.google.com");
```